# How to stop NUnit TestRunner?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nunit, testdriven.net

I am unit testing a C# solution using **NUnit** Version 3.9.0.0 (Runtime Version v4.0.30319, tried different versions up to 3.10.0.1) from within VS 2017 Enterprise, TestDriven.Net V 4.1-Alpha, OS Windows 10 Pro.
The project's assemblies target .Net 4.0.

In most cases it works fine, but sometimes the behavior of **NUnit** becomes unpredictable, so that the system is no longer to work with. What actually happens is, I am starting a very simple unit test, and it gets through. Then I am starting the same test again, and the system gets stuck. You cannot stop the testing thread, as in the image below (the red rocket icon does not react on right mouse click):

[image]

I was also unable to find the relevant process in the process manager to manually kill it. 
The NUnit items in the context menu remain gray and there is no way to stop/restart the test from within it, see below:

[image]

The only possibility is to restart VS completely, then you can carry out exactly one test, and everything starts again. What can be possibly wrong?

Comment: I added testdriven.net label. The problem appears to be a premature termination of the nunit agent process, not noticed by td.net. It's td.net that creates and enables/disables all those menu items.

Comment: Thanks Charlie, this is what I suspect, too. But do you know how to manually terminate the nunit process? I cannot find it with the process manager.

Comment: If TestDriven.net doesn't stop by itself, you can kill process ProcessInvocation86.exe.  Its not ideal, but a way to be able to continue without having to restart VS.

Answer (score 1):

Not enough room in a comment, so...

I suspect that TD.Net may be able to run tests either in or out of process. If it runs out of process using NUnit's own agent, then you will see a process running `nunit-agent.exe` or `nunit-agent-x86.exe`. You could kill that process if you like.

However, what this sounds like is that the process is crashing and terminating. The problem could easily be that TD.Net doesn't notice that has happened. It's waiting for a signal from the process to indicate the run is complete. If that's the case, then it will never re-enable the disabled controls.

You can test this by running some tests that **don't** cause the problem under TD.NET. This should be a test run that takes a while, so you have time to kill the agent process. Watch to see what TD.Net does. Does it notice you killed the process? If not, you have a problem to report to TD.Net. If it does notice and re-enable the controls, then we have not yet understood the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Charlie, interesting information. Will try it next time it gets stuck.